# How to synchronize Basler camera, robot controller (ABB) and Visual Studio?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, robotics

I wrote a C++ program in Visual Studio for anomaly detection using OpenCV. I'm now able to capture images with Basler Ace camera and process the captured image in visual studio. Camera is connected to computer directly with USB 3.0.

My next step is to synchronize image capturing and processing with robot movement. I have IRB1440 ABB robot.

What are the possible solutions for this? Should I buy expensive Siemens PLCs ? Can the solution be found in any other way? What type of communication should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very specific question on a commercial product. I suggest you contact ABBs support and read the robot controllers manual. There you will find information on how to interface it in a safe manner.

It is not the robot you want to talk to, it is its controller!

According to the info I found on IRB 1440 (seem to be a sub-model of IRB1400) the controller is a S4Cplus.

The way we usually do it is a Windows PC based image processing system that is hooked up to a PLC (Siemens, Mitsubishi,...) which forwards our coordinates, angles and whatnot to the robot controller.
Of course the PLC can be omitted if your PC is the "boss" of the entire system.

[S4Cplus Product Specifications](http://www02.abb.com/global/nlabb/nlabb034.nsf/bf177942f19f4a98c1257148003b7a0a/bbce2cfacf64e51ec1256f5b004835fd/$FILE/S4Cplus_Rev5.pdf)

This controller comes with various interfacing options including RS232, RS422, Ethernet as well as a whole bunch of industry standards.

Having a separate PLC is not necessary as the controller may serve as a PLC itself, although you might have to upgrade the controller using so called I/O nodes.

But as I said, refer to the manuals and ABB support.

Obviously any non-realtime solution like a Windows PC is not an option for any safety features.